# weighted mean in dplyr for multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, weighted

I'm trying to calculate the weighted mean for multiple columns using dplyr. at the moment I'm stuck with summarize_each which to me seems to be part of the solution. here's some example code:

```
library(dplyr)
f2a <- c(1,0,0,1)
f2b <- c(0,0,0,1)
f2c <- c(1,1,1,1)
clustervar <- c("A","B","B","A")
weight <- c(10,20,30,40)

df <- data.frame (f2a, f2b, f2c, clustervar, weight, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df
```

what I am looking for is something like

```
df %>%
  group_by (clustervar) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(weighted.mean(weight)), select=cbind(clustervar, f2a:f2c))
```

The result of this is only:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  clustervar select4 select5 select6
       <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1          A      25      25      25
2          B      25      25      25
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `summarise_at` to specify which columns you want to operate on:

```r
df %>% group_by(clustervar) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('f2')), 
                 funs(weighted.mean(., weight)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   clustervar   f2a   f2b   f2c
#>        <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1          A     1   0.8     1
#> 2          B     0   0.0     1
```

Comment: Thanks Alistaire! I missed the ., for funs, too

Answer (score 1):

We can reshape it to 'long' format and then do this

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df, Var, Val, f2a:f2c) %>% 
        group_by(clustervar, Var) %>% 
        summarise(wt =weighted.mean(Val, weight)) %>%
        spread(Var, wt)
```

---

Or another option is

```
df %>%
    group_by(clustervar) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(weighted.mean(., weight)), matches("^f"))
# A tibble: 2 × 4     
#    clustervar   f2a   f2b   f2c
#         <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1          A     1   0.8     1
# 2          B     0   0.0     1
```

---

Or with `summarise_at` and `matches` (another variation of another post - didn't see the other post while posting)

```
df %>% 
   group_by(clustervar) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(matches('f2')), funs(weighted.mean(., weight)))
# A tibble: 2 × 4
#   clustervar   f2a   f2b   f2c
#        <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1          A     1   0.8     1
#2          B     0   0.0     1
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) weighted.mean(x, weight)),
                       by = clustervar, .SDcols  = f2a:f2c]
#    clustervar f2a f2b f2c
#1:          A   1 0.8   1
#2:          B   0 0.0   1
```

NOTE: All four answers are based on legitimate `tidyverse/data.table` syntax and would get the expected output

We can also create a function that makes use of the syntax from devel version of dplyr (soon to be released 0.6.0). The enquo does the similar job of substitute by taking the input arguments and converting it to quosures. Within the group_by/summarise/mutate, we evalute the quosure by unquoting (UQ or !!) it

```
wtFun <- function(dat, pat, wtcol, grpcol){
       wtcol <- enquo(wtcol)
       grpcol <- enquo(grpcol)
       dat %>%
           group_by(!!grpcol) %>%
           summarise_at(vars(matches(pat)), funs(weighted.mean(., !!wtcol)))
 }

wtFun(df, "f2", weight, clustervar)
# A tibble: 2 × 4
#   clustervar   f2a   f2b   f2c
#       <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1          A     1   0.8     1
#2          B     0   0.0     1
```

Comment: Please do not delete downvoted answers just to re-post them in an attempt to clear downvotes. This is considered an abuse of the system, and is not acceptable. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331598/dodging-downvotes-by-deletion-and-repost) for more.